# Algebraic independence of limit cycles of Lienard equation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, limit-cycles

[It is  well known that](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1995JDE...115..146O) the  Van der Pol equation $$\begin{cases} \dot x=y-(x^3-x)\\\dot y=-x \end{cases}$$ has no an algebraic limit  cycle.

According to this  fact, we search  for  a related question in the  following form:

We  consider  the  Lienard equation $$\begin{cases} \dot x=y-F(x)\\ 
\dot y=-x\end{cases}$$

where $F(x)$ is  a polynomial with real  coefficient.

> Is there an example  of  a  Lienard equation as the  above  system  with two  distinct limit cycles $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$  with a polynomial or rational map  $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$  such that $g(\gamma_1)=\gamma_2$?

Comment: @Mahdi  I assume $F(x)$ is  a  polynomial  function in $x$. In the  classical Lienard equation, $F$ is a  polynomial.

Comment: @Mahdi  But the  system has no  LIMIT  CYCLE  when  F=x.  So  actually we  start  from  degree F=3. For  deg(F)=2 we  have  no  limit cycle.  There is  a  LNM paper I think(LNM 598)  by  Pugh, Lins  Neto  and  W. de melo the  title is  "On  Lienard equation". In that paper one  can  find more  explanation  on this  system.

Comment: @Mahdi  This  is  the  exact  address (1977) Lins Neto, de Melo and Pugh [Lectures Notes in. Math. 597, 335–357]

Comment: Thanks, for responses. I will delete my disturbing comments, soon.

Comment: @Mahdi  I thank you too  for  your attention to my question. Your comment was not disturbing.